# how we sort search result according the keyword occurrence in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

below is my query :

This query is work fine but now i wish this query result is sort by keyword occurrence.
Example:
In my database :

```
srno| name          | business                         |city 
  - | ------------- | -------------------------------  |-------
  1 | janefer group | advertisement company import     |manchester
  2 | abc           | golf import export               |new york
  3 | xyz           | golf import                      |new york
```

and if i pass keyword in search box
`$search ="golf import export xyz";`

**then i want result like where all keyword match this post come first and so on**

## Query

```
$qry="SELECT *, MATCH (name,business,city) AGAINST ('$serach*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance FROM tbl_services WHERE MATCH (name,business,city) AGAINST ('$serach*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY Relevance DESC LIMIT 1 , 12"
```

Comment: why can't you try like in query

Comment: because i want full search and partial keyword search so i use match and against

Comment: when i use like its not search against full and partial keyword

Comment: in $search how will concatenate business and name?

Comment: make a three field in seperate three varaibles like

Comment: $srch_business = 'golf'; $srch_name='xyz';$srch_city='new'

Comment: $search i pass in AGAINST i think thats concatenate with name and business

Comment: ok what output you get?

Comment: sir still not show output like my requirement

Answer (score 0):

you mispelled the word $search  in query try this

```
$qry="SELECT *, MATCH (name,business,city) AGAINST ('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance FROM tbl_services WHERE MATCH (name,business,city) AGAINST ('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY Relevance DESC LIMIT 1 , 12"
```

Comment: still not work ...i wish its sort according to my requirement but still no

Comment: i want out like when we get result from query then that's post become first that have matching more keyword and so on ...and the post that have matching less keyword it display at the end

Answer (score 0):

I wish out like below where many keyword match the post show first and so on
$seach "golf import export xyz";

become first post because have many matching keyword:
name : abc
business: golf import export 
city: new york

second post:
name :xyz
business: golf import
city :new york